# Django download not starting even though HTTP response is 200

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to create a zip file full of .wav files and download it from a React front end, which is making an AJAX request to the Django endpoint.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def saveZipFile(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    in_memory = BytesIO()
    zipFile = ZipFile(in_memory, "a")


    keys = generate_piano_keys(3)
    # activeNotes = {}
    for index, key in enumerate(keys):
        nameOfFile = request.POST.get(key) 
        if(nameOfFile != None):
            zipFile.write('./{}'.format(nameOfFile), arcname="{}.wav".format(key))

    for file in zipFile.filelist:
        file.create_system = 0

    zipFile.close()
    downloadFile = in_memory.getvalue()
    in_memory.seek(0)

    response = HttpResponse(in_memory.getvalue(), content_type='application/zip') 
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="sample_map.zip"'
    return response
```

I am getting the following response from the Django server: `"POST /test/saveZipFile HTTP/1.1" 200 61894`

I have tried debugging the response.content and it is the same bytes as the bytes I am writing to the zipFile variable, which means that it is getting written to the response. I have tried using `application/force-download` instead of `application/zip` in the content_type.

Is there something I am missing, since every thread and article says that it should look like that.

The request is done through axios:

```
const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: window.location.href + "saveZipFile",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": token
    }
  });
```

the data object is just a bunch of file names.

Comment: It looks a bit "odd" to use a POST request. Normally this is done through a GET request.

Comment: Just tried with a GET request, still not downloading

Comment: Show your AJAX code.

Comment: Just made an edit

Comment: I just tried using Postman and it works, but in browsers it does not, I tried Chrome and Mozilla already.